# Как обновить зависимую сущность не потеряв ссылку на родительскую Spring Data Jpa Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-jpa

Это мои энтити:

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private UserStatus status;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")
    private Role role;

    @Column(name = "refresh_token")
    private String refreshToken;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Task> tasks;
}

============================

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

import javax.persistence.*;

@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
@Data
public class Task extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "position")
    private Long position;

    @Column(name = "status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TaskStatus status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

Когда я обновляю `title` в классе `Task`, ссылка на `user` становится null. Я пробоваа сделать `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` и `{CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE}` в классе `Task` и  `User` поочереди, но это не сработало. Что можно сделать чтобы избежать потери задания юзера?

Обновление происходит так:

```
tasksRepository.save(task);
```

Comment: каким путем происходит обновление?

Comment: @lampa обновила вопрос

Comment: Понятнее не стало) Через контроллер из объекта DTO или как-то modelAttribute используете или вынимаете через репозиторий?

Comment: Точно! Нашла ошибку, ща покажу

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка (глупая) была вот в чем: таска получалась в контроллере как DTO, и мапилась без юзера:

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PATCH})
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public TaskOutDto createUpdateTask(@RequestBody @Valid TaskInDto task) {
        Task taskToSave = mapper.fromDto(task);
        taskToSave = taskService.save(taskToSave);
        return mapper.toDto(taskToSave);
    }
```

Решение было следующим - проверить, есть ли таск, и если да то не ставить ему юзера как null:

```
@Override
    @CacheEvict(allEntries = true)
    public Task save(Task taskToSave) {
        AtomicReference<Task> taskToReturn = new AtomicReference<>(taskToSave);

        if (taskToSave.getId() != null) {
            tasksRepository.findById(taskToSave.getId())
                    .ifPresent(task -> {
                        task.setTitle(taskToSave.getTitle());
                        task.setDescription(taskToSave.getDescription());
                        task.setPosition(taskToSave.getPosition());
                        task.setStatus(taskToSave.getStatus());

                        taskToReturn.set(task);
                    });
        }
        return tasksRepository.save(taskToReturn.get());
    }
```

Comment: еее!) Можно еще уйти от DTO, переиспользуя сам entity, заполняя энтити через modelAttribute механизм

Comment: Низя, rest + фронт отдельно((